# hide password reveal in IE does not work

Tags: css

The following does not work for IE11 for me:

```
input::-ms-clear, input::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```

Side-issue, probably not relevant: Whether I have it in or not I get the same thing, which I'm guessing is the way this works: the first time you go into password field you get the show/hide icon, change fields, go back in and the icon disappears.

any ideas how to get rid of the reveal because I have to remove it?

thanks.

Comment: Try separating the rules instead of merging them together and see if that works. For things like the placeholder pseudo selector you need to have them on separate lines. I think this will be the same issue.

Comment: hmm. It's working when I put this in a separate file, so something in my stylesheet must be negating it. I'll put it at the end with an important, but I don't see how another style can override this (there are no other -ms entries in my stylesheet though)

Comment: Strange, give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: adding !important fixed it. Sorry, so it did work, something must be reversing this, but there is hontestly no -ms entries anywhere else.

Comment: I would suggest posting your CSS so we can see perhaps? Although if it's working now, I guess it's answered. No worries.

Comment: See my 'answer' below, there is a full scattering of CSS and embedded stuff using GWT (by a third party) but I have checked all the files by hand and found nothing. IE developer mode doesn't seem to want to list -ms css entries so it's hard to see for sure.

Answer (score 0):

adding !important to the rule fixed it. Something, somewhere must have overridden this, but there are no other -ms* entries in the imported style sheets and html (however this is tricky as it uses the truly awful GWT which seems to obfuscate and hide everything)....

Answer (score -1):

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    color: red; /* This sets the cross color as red. */ 
}
```

Comment: this does nothing?